# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): System.Net.Security.Native error shows up for localhost server but not on an online server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine, server, ssms

so I've been stuck with this error for a few days now and I can't see to get it to work.
I'm trying to get a my unity application (computer platform, not android) to connect to my localhost server (I use Microsoft SQL Server Express)  using Microsoft SQL Server Manager. Here's my code:

```
public void connect(){
      Debug.Log("Connecting to Server");
      string connectionStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";
      
      SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);

      try
      {
          dbConnection.Open();
          Debug.Log("Connected");
      }
      catch(SqlException exception)
      {
          Debug.LogWarning(exception.ToString());
      }

       
      }
  }
```

This code works when I used an online server but when I changed the connection string for my local server, it gave me the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): System.Net.Security.Native

I believe it is either from the server itself or from the connection string. I tried to look this up online but they usually have to do with Xamarian/Android errors, or I've already tried their suggestions, and I'm a noob with databases. Can someone help me with this or at least tell me why this error appears?

*I have TCP/IP Enabled and I am currently using Windows

Edit: Full error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): System.Net.Security.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+NetSecurityNative.ImportPrincipalName(Interop/NetSecurityNative/Status&,string,int,Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle&)
  at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle.CreatePrincipal (System.String name) [0x0000e] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.String targetName) [0x0001c] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& context, System.String targetName, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal inFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& outFlags) [0x0000b] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, System.String spn, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer[] inSecurityBufferArray, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outSecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags) [0x0002a] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.Byte[] serverName) [0x0006b] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength, System.Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer) [0x00000] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength) [0x00007] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
System.Net.Security.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+NetSecurityNative.ImportPrincipalName(Interop/NetSecurityNative/Status&,string,int,Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle&)
  at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeGssNameHandle.CreatePrincipal (System.String name) [0x0000e] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteNegoContext..ctor (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.String targetName) [0x0001c] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.EstablishSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeNegoCredentials credential, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& context, System.String targetName, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal inFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& outFlags) [0x0000b] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.InitializeSecurityContext (System.Net.Security.SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, System.String spn, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer[] inSecurityBufferArray, System.Net.Security.SecurityBuffer outSecurityBuffer, System.Net.ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags) [0x0002a] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GenSspiClientContext (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SspiClientContextStatus sspiClientContextStatus, System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.Byte[] serverName) [0x0006b] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.GenerateSspiClientContext (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength, System.Byte[] _sniSpnBuffer) [0x00000] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SNISSPIData (System.Byte[] receivedBuff, System.UInt32 receivedLength, System.Byte[]& sendBuff, System.UInt32& sendLength) [0x00007] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, System.Object at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, System.Object providerInfo, System.Boolean redirectedUserInstance, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData reconnectSessionData, System.Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) [0x00156] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, System.Object poolGroupProviderInfo, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x0012a] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x0000c] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00184] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00040] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, System.Boolean allowCreate, System.Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x000a4] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x00026] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x0021d] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal (System.Data.Common.DbConnection outerConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x00036] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection (System.Data.Common.DbConnection outerConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x00000] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry) [0x0005d] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x0003b] in <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0 
  at DbManager.connect ()
```

Comment: There's exactly this question posted on answers.unity: http://answers.unity.com/answers/1649879/view.html

Comment: Also since you're using integrated security (windows account) likely it means your local account does not have access to the server - add a sql user  and then use an SQL account https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/standard-security/

Comment: @sommmen I've already checked out the post, and while he has the same error, he didn't put enough information for anyone to answer while I did. Also, this is a local server not an online one. I just used the online server as test but it's the local server that is currently on my computer that I want to connect on.

Comment: 'he didn't put enough information for anyone to answer' neither did you - how about you just use a console application to test connecting with the database real quickly so you know you have the connection strings right? Also does the (inner) exception object not have any additional info?

Comment: @sommmen I added the info of what people usually ask for, if it isn't enough I apologize. I did test the connection using a .udl file and the Visual Studio's Server Explorer thingy (They both said connected). That is also where I got the connection string from since Visual Studio auto generates it. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'inner' - do you mean by what came after the 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): System.Net.Security.Native' exception? It's a bit long

Comment: I added the full error

Comment: As you don’t demonstrate the connection string. The first comment seems most likely

Comment: @BugFinder the connection string is string connectionStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";. It's in the code I put up there. I am not trying to connect to a mysql server, Im trying to connect to a local ssms server. I get that its the same problem as the link in the first problem but there are no answers that tell me what it is caused by.

Comment: Then yes. The first comment would be the moat likely answer

Comment: @BugFinder I'm sorry, I dont seem to understand the answer then. If you dont mind, can you please explain to me by what Im supposed to do or what it is according to the answer? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Then you need to read up on mssql authentication snd of course read the logs